# Multiple filter by array of object in Elastic 6.*

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net, elasticsearch-query

Need help with building query through the array in ElasticSearch 6. I have documents that represent some property units with a number of attributes:

```
{  
   "Unit":{
     "Attributes":{  
        "Attribute":[  
           {  
              "Name":"Elevator",
              "Text":"No"
           },
           {  
              "Name":"Pet Friendly",
              "Text":"Yes"
           }
        ...
        ]   
      }        
   }
}
```

How can I filter my documents to find all pet friendly units or all units without elevator?

P.S. I am using NEST.

Comment: may I know your schema mapping for this?

Comment: @bhoo-day, the issue is solved. But I would be very pleased, if you take a look on my new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50717706/regexp-starts-with-not-working-elasticsearch-6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Map `Attribute`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/mapping.html) as a [`nested` type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html), probably with `Text` mapped as `keyword` for term level matching. To query, use a [`bool` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html) with `filter` clauses, where the clauses will be [`nested` queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/nested-query-usage.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helps. Could you please take a look on my next question? =) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50717706/regexp-starts-with-not-working-elasticsearch-6